# How to format a string value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string-formatting, string-function

Say there is a varchar column `account_id` all of them are 10 integer like `1234567890`.
How can I format a value like `1234567890` to `123-456-7890` in mysql?

```
1234567890  => 123-456-7890
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
concat(
    substring(account_id,1,3),
    '-',
    substring(account_id,4,3),
    '-',
    substring(account_id,7,4)
)
```

Comment: I've tried with `CONCAT(LEFT(account_id, 3),'-',LEFT(RIGHT(account_id, 7),3),'-', RIGHT(account_id, 4))`. Could you please give me some advice about which one is better on execution considering?

Comment: I doubt there's a noticable difference.  That will definitely be different if the value is longer or shorter than 10.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use [CONCAT_WS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat_ws.asp) function:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-',
    LEFT(account_id, 3), -- first 3 symbols
    MID(account_id, 4, LENGTH(account_id)-7), -- rest middle symbols
    RIGHT(account_id, 4) -- last 4 symbols
);
```